# How to focus already opened window using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var memwin = window.open(mylink, winName, "toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, height=590,width=1200");
window.memwin.focus();
```

This code opens a new tab, and focuses on subsequent open() calls regardless if focus() is called or not. in case of **Chrome 20**, i want to do the same in **Firefox 13**.Is there any alternate or jquery code which help me do that.

Comment: The window option list shouldn't have spaces between the options i.e. toolbar=yeas,scrollbar=yes,.... (I can't find the documentation for this but it maybe burried somewhere here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Comment: This link was extremely help full thanks a lot jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do that one u can change the settings of your Firefox 
i.e.
Total facepalm moment: In FireFox:

- Tools
- Options…
- Content tab
- Advanced button next to “Enable JavaScript”
- check the box named "Raise or Lower Windows"
  other is u try this code:

  `function windowopenfunc(newlink, winName, winName1, access, tme) {
  window.name = winName1;
  if(access == "A" || tme == "2nd"){
      if(memwin == null || memwin.closed){
          memwin = window.open(newlink, winName, "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,height=590,width=1200");
      }
      else if(previouslink != newlink){
          memwin = window.open(newlink, winName, "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,height=590,width=1200");
          memwin.focus();
      }
      else{
          memwin.focus();
      };
      previouslink = newlink;
  }
  }`